# What is the use of Java Enum class methods valueOf() and name()?

Tags: enums

I don't understand the use of name() method based on its usage.

**Example**:

```
enum DAY {
    MON, TUE, WED 
};
```

The usage is:

```
DAY.MON.name(); // returns MON which we already have passed.
```

Method `valueOf()` is functioning in the same way. Can anyone give a clear explanation on this?

Answer (score 0):

**valueOf()** method returns the enum constant of the specified enumtype with the specified name, whereas **name()** method returns the name of this enum constant, exactly as declared in its enum declaration

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply  :)